# Git: remove latest commit and previous merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I want to remove the latest (pushed) commit and the previous merge as well.

this is how my git-tree currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I can't find a solution to this exact tree-problem, and I don't want to screw anything up. So I thought I'd be better off asking for help.

I'm using GitKraken as well, so a GUI-based solution would be as sufficient as a command-line based.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure anyone who might have already fetched the merge and post-merge commits is on board with you rewriting history like this. If not, I would use `git revert` to create a *new* commit that effectively undoes the merge while preserving the fact that the merge had once been made.

Comment: It's literally impossible to *remove* a commit directly. What you end up doing, when you use `git push --force` or similar, is directing the other Git repository to *stop using* the commits. Whether and when it actually drops those commits entirely from its repository is up to it, if it even obeys your command to make it stop using those commits on its branch in the first place. Note that if those commits have infected some *other* (third) Git repository by this time, you can't get *that* repo to forget them either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to reset master to masterCommit2 and push master with force flag.

```
git switch master
git reset --hard masterCommit2
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `--force-with-lease` here instead of `--force`. If a new commit (commit4) appeared on `master` between the time you last fetched, and when you attempt the push, you probably want to know about it so you can decide if you need to cherry-pick commit4 afterwards, or rethink this and do a revert instead.